# Problem with button.setOnclickListener(this)

Tags: java, android, xml

I started learning android, I'm trying to make a login activity but my buttons doesn't work for any reason.

I have implemented view.OnClickListener in my class

Here's my java code :

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btn_login, btn_reset;
    private EditText et_username, et_pwd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login_login);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_log_reset);
        btn_reset.setOnClickListener(this);

        et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_log_username);
        et_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_log_password);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.w("test","test");
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bt_login_login :
                DisplayData();
                break;

            case R.id.bt_log_reset :
                resetData();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if this was not caused by the fact that my buttons are in a tree like this :

activity_login.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_username"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_log_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_login"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_log_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/pwd"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_login_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/intro_login"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_log_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reset"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ps : I may have a bad english, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use anonymous class to implement your listeners? Just curious.

Comment: I've already tried with an anonymous class but it didn't change anything

Comment: Do you see "test" in your Logcat? (because you have this line  `Log.w("test","test");` in `onClick()` )

Comment: No, it's doesn't display in the Logcat

Comment: Please add the `class LoginActivity...` statement to your code - maybe something is missing there

Comment: @CGDrakwars is the xml you posted part of `activity_login.xml`? Is it maybe in an include xml?

Comment: It's part of activity_login.xml

Comment: Post the whole xml.

Comment: I've edited the post with the whole xml

Comment: This should work, I don't see anything unusual. Don't worry about the tree structure in the xml file, this is no problem at all. I'm wondering if you have implemented anything else which catches touch events before they reach the Buttons?

Comment: brother i copy pasted your code, it's working just fine, make sure you are importing the right classes, ( i did remove your @string/names though)

Comment: *i didn't linked the ativity_login.xml with the Login.class* you have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); ` what do you mean link?

Comment: Your code is proper. make sure are you using Login activity

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your activity `implements View.OnClickListener`
everything else seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approch. You can pass an **anonymous class** implementation of OnClickListener when using setOnClickListener.

Another way to do it is define an onClick attribute in the xml for each button, give it a functions name. You will have to have a function with the exact name in the activity for the function to be triggered (Android Studio will not let the project compile without a proper connection between them.)

The anonymous class implementation is prefered, as you will not be able to declare events in the xml all the time (when using fragments for example).

to implement an anonymous class in the setOnclickListener do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //stuff to do when the button was clicked goes here. 
        }
    });
```

Comment: *Your mistake is thinking the activity/class is the listener* why is this a mistake? Take a look at Joe Matt's answer.

Comment: Its a design mistake, it CAN be a listener for that case, but what if we were to add more event listeners, would the activity be responsible to implement all of them?
Using anonymous classes is a much better design solution

Comment: This is not a design mistake. It's a central way of handling click events. *if we were to add more event listeners, would the activity be responsible to implement all of them?* it would if the designer wants to. That is the use of `switch()`.

Comment: Anyway your answer does not solve the OP's problem. He wants to know why the `onClick()` which seems to be fine is not invoked.

Comment: If you want to talk about what the OP asked in his question, it was if the xml structure is causing the onClick not to work, and the answer to that is no, it seems like a decent xml structure to me. I have edited my answer, to provide an alternative solution.